# How do I create a simple navigation view for my iOS app using swift

Tags: ios, swift, gps, mapkit

I am trying to create a very simple navigation view controller for my master detail application.  I am using swift (2) and have the following code:

```
import MapKit
import UIKit
import CoreData
import CoreLocation

class DirectionsViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var point1 = MKPointAnnotation()
    var point2 = MKPointAnnotation()
    var myRoute : MKRoute?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        // For use in foreground
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
        point1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locValue.latitude, locValue.longitude) //code to sync in current location
        point1.title = "You are here"
        point1.subtitle = "Start"
        mapView.addAnnotation(point1)
        // to test location  - print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")

        point2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.22396739999999, -74.0303199)
        point2.title = "First Pentecostal Church"
        point2.subtitle = "Neptune, NJ"
        mapView.addAnnotation(point2)
        mapView.centerCoordinate = point2.coordinate
        mapView.delegate = self
        //Span of the map
        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(point2.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.7,0.7)), animated: true)

        var directionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        let markUser = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point1.coordinate.latitude, point1.coordinate.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)
        let markFPC = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point2.coordinate.latitude, point2.coordinate.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)

        directionsRequest.setSource(MKMapItem(placemark: markUser))
        directionsRequest.setDestination(MKMapItem(placemark: markFPC))
        directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Automobile
        var directions = MKDirections(request: directionsRequest)
        directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler { (response:MKDirectionsResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.myRoute = response.routes[0] as? MKRoute
                self.mapView.addOverlay(self.myRoute?.polyline)
            }
        }
    }
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {

        var myLineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: myRoute?.polyline!)
        myLineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
        myLineRenderer.lineWidth = 3
        return myLineRenderer
    }

}
```

I get no response in the simulator and I am not sure where I went wrong.  I believe this is swift 2.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: After doing some reading I am wondering if the issue is with the simulator.  I m not sure if the GPS function is just not working, or if I just have bad code. If someone is willing to test the code above to confirm my error I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to run your code, I too don't get anything on the map, even though the locationservices is initialized and (apparently) working.

But, I do get the following warning in the console:

> This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a
>   usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.

So, adding the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`to your plist file, and your will get updates from the location services.

Comment: I will add it and re run this evening.  Thank you.

Comment: That definitely got a response.  It looks like I have a few more things to work on, but thank you that was the issue!!!